# Key annotation not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I'm getting the following error:

> Error 1   The type or namespace name 'keyAttribute' could not be found 
>   (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> enter code here
>
> c:\users\hp\documents\visual studio
>   2013\Projects\ProductApps\ProductApps\Models\Product.cs   13  10  ProductApps

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;


namespace ProductApps.Models
{
    public class Product
    {
        [key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
        public string Price { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is anyone able to suggest why I'm getting the error and how to fix it?

Comment: Did you try to use is a Primary key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
```

to your using statements and try like (With capital K)

```
[Key]
public int Id { get; set; }
```

Comment: Thanks #vgSefa. It was small letter of the annotation name 'key'; thats why I am getting error. Now Its working :)

Answer (score -1):

Do you have the `System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll` assembly referenced in your project?

Comment: I should mention that I am a beginner of MVC. How can I find that whether I added System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll it or not?

Comment: @masudshrabon In the Project Explorer, you can find it under "References". If it is not there, right click on "References" and select "Add reference".